# Keeping a object(world space canvas) always in the cameras viewport

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have the following problem: I have a world space canvas following a arrow that moves around the screen. The canvas itself is just a child of the arrow. The problem is that sometimes when the arrow is pointing to something on the edge of the screen parts of the canvas go off screen. I want to write some code that keeps the entire canvas inside the viewport at all times. I found a solution online but this keeps the pivot point of the object inside the camera bounds and not the whole object. I simply cant figure out how to keep the whole object inside the camera bounds. Here is the code I have :

```
void LateUpdate()
{
  transform.rotation = rotation;// This simply keeps the objects original rotation independant from the parent
  Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
  pos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.x);
  pos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.y);
  transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define some sort of bounding box around your `GameObject` and then check if all corner points are inside the Viewport (and if not move the object)

For defining a bounding rectangle you can either use a `BoxCollider` which is set to be a trigger (to prevent it from colliding with its surroundings). Using the Colliders `Center` and `Size` you can determine all the corner points and use these for your bounds checking.

If you don't want to use colliders, you can write a simple class/struct in which you can define the center and extends of an imaginary bounding box (maybe use `Gizmos` to draw it in the editor, to see how large it is and how it is positioned).

Hope this helps.

**Edit**
Okay, as you mentioned you can use `GetWorldCorners` to retrieve the 3D corner points. To check if these are in the viewport, you simply transform them using `Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint` and check if their x and y components are in [0, 1]. If now for example your canvas going out of screen on the right side, the 2 right corners points will have an x component value >1, e.g. 1.5, which means it has to be moved by `(-0.5, 0)` (viewport coordinates). You could now try to shift the center of the canvas in viewport coordinates by `(-0.5, 0)` and project the resulting point in world space. This projected point would be the point where the center of your canvas should be.

If you want to be more precise and also want to rotate the 3d canvas, you could shift and transform all 4 corner points and move/rotate the canvas accordingly

Comment: well since it is a RectTransform there is a build it GetWorldCorners method to get the 4 corners of the rect transform. What I cant figure out is how to check if they are in the viewport and how to move the object after that.